# Redirect entire site to URL with 302 - All URLs to 1 URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

What i want to do is redirect an entire forum temporarily to a Twitter Page.

However anything i've tried hasnt worked.

If they visit for example site.com/Forum it will send them to twitter.com/ourpageForum

How do i just redirect them to twitter.com/ourpage **with a 302** no matter what Forum URL they visit?

Thanks

Comment: For simple scenario's like the one above [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html) is sufficient and is both faster and doesn't have the learning curve of mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apache [RedirectMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) directive is a fairly trivial method to do as you ask:

```
RedirectMatch temp ^/Forum/.* http://twitter.com/ourpageForum
```

`temp` returns a temporary redirect status (302).

Comment: Thanks and does that redirect all URLs? Im not looking to just redirect the Forum but the entire site which is mainly a forum. Sorry for being confusing.

Comment: Its not just the /Forum URL i want to redirect is what im saying. I just need the root site.com/ and all subfolders redirected. Im waiting on DNS to propagate and cant test right now but i will soon.

Comment: Ah my mistake... `RedirectMatch temp ^.* http://twitter.com/ourpageForum` should do that!

Comment: Seems to just time out if i go to site.com/Forum but works if i go to site.com

Comment: And you wouldn't have another .htaccess file in the Forum directory?

Comment: Spot on! Works 100%.